# Programatic Access to Company Shared Outlook Contacts in Web App

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-api

I have created a public folder mailbox and a root public folder for our organization in Office 365.  I've also created a Shared Contacts folder in Outlook and added a couple of contacts.

Now I want to be able to programatically access these shared contacts (list, view, add, remove) in our web application, an SPA written in Angular4.

We are already authenticating against Azure AD, and we are already pulling information from [MS Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/).  However I don't see any way to access public folders in Graph.

How can I access these shared contacts in our web app?  I'm open to using something other than MS Graph, if there is another REST API that does what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, public folder access is still not available through the Graph API (or any other REST API).

You need to use Exchange Web Services (EWS). 
Public folder access with EWS is described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj945067(v=exchg.150).aspx.